# Filling NAs with manipulation of leading values

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's suppose my data looks something like the first two columns of the following extract (it has many more observations).

```
ID  Value Value_Filled
762 2     2
762 2     2
763 NA    7
763 8     8
763 9     9
```

What I'm trying to do is to use dplyr to fill up all NA-values per ID-group with the leading value minus 1 (like in the column named Value_Filled).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `mutate_at`, include columns to check in `vars` argument and replace `NA` in every column with it's `lead` value minus 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% #Maybe you need this, doesn't change anything for this example
  mutate_at(vars(Value, Value_Filled), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), lead(.) - 1, .))

#  ID Value Value_Filled
#1 762     2            2
#2 762     2            2
#3 763     7            7
#4 763     8            8
#5 763     9            9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `mutate` a new column with an `ifelse`statement to check for a `NA`value:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(ID = c(762L, 762L, 763L, 763L, 763L), Value = c(2L, 
2L, NA, 8L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

df_filled <- df %>% mutate(value_filled = ifelse(is.na(.$Value),as.integer(substr(as.character(.$ID),1,1)),.$Value))
```

Comment: Of course my data frame has many more observations than the extract shown here and also not all values I want to fill in correspond to the ID's first character. So I'm afraid I'll need a more generalizable solution.

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example. If there are more conditions you have to check for more conditions. This solution in theory is generalizable. But to do this you need to provide a dataset that describes your whole problem. My answer answers the question you asked.